# 'if not "giveaway rig" in str(ctx.command): AttributeError: 'CheckFailure' object has no attribute 'command'` Can you tell how to fix this?

Tags: command, discord, discord.py, attributeerror

This is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if not "giveaway rig" in str(ctx.command):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
            pass
        elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await send_cmd_help(ctx)
        elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
            await send_cmd_help(ctx)
    else:
        await ctx.bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, defaultGiveawayErrorMessage)
```

And when it runs, this error shows:

```
if not "giveaway rig" in str(ctx.command):
AttributeError: 'CheckFailure' object has no attribute 'command'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

### The issue at hand:

You've got your event's parameters the wrong way round.
Swap them around like so:

```
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
```

---

### Discord.py version:

And from the looks of things, you seem to be using some async code:

```
await ctx.bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, defaultGiveawayErrorMessage)
```

which, in rewrite (`v1.x`), can be written as:

```
await ctx.send(defaultGiveawayErrorMessage)
```

The rewrite and async versions of d.py **are not compatible,** and you will need to update your version of d.py.
You can do this by running:

```
pip install -U discord.py
```

and you'll know whether you have the rewrite version judging by if you see this in your output:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: discord.py in c:\PATH\TO\python\python35\lib\site-packages (1.X.X)
```

(Note the version number at the end)

---

### Some issues that may arise:

1. You've got it installed successfully, but running your script errors when using rewrite's documentation.

> **Cause:** This is because you may be trying to run the script on a version of python that `discord.py` wasn't installed on.
>
> ---
>
> **Fixes:**
>
> - If this was done in a virtual environment, it should be an easy enough fix - just open up the venv's terminal and make sure you run the command there (not in your cmd prompt!).
> - If you're not using a venv, it'd be your best bet to just make sure you have **one version of Python installed**.

2. Whenever you run the command `pip install -U discord.py`, you're only getting `v0.16.x` installed.

> **Cause:** You're installing the package on an outdated version of Python.
>
> ---
>
> **Fixes:**
>
> - discord.py, as of this answer, only supports Python versions 3.5.3 and above.
>   This means that you need to upgrade your version of Python.
> - If you're still encountering this issue and you're *sure* you've got a version of 3.5.3 or above, check the [current versions of Python that discord.py supports](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py#discordpy). A nice and simple fix for this is to make sure you only have **one version of Python installed** again.

---

And with that being said, I highly recommend using the rewrite docs, and if you want to follow any tutorials, make sure they're up-to-date (include `rewrite` as a keyword in your searches).

The rewrite version is much, much nicer than async, and at first it may be a bit difficult to get to grips with what's changed, which is what [this page](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#major-model-changes) is for. It'll help build the foundations for your migration to the newer d.py version.

---

### References:

- [Major model changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#major-model-changes) - Moving from async to rewrite, I highly recommend reading through this, as it could fix any issues that you run into when you get started.
- [OS-specific installations](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py#installing) - For if you're still running into issues during installation.
- [`on_command_error()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_error)
- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) - You will, depending on what your bot does, be using context instances a LOT of the time. Get familiar with what attributes and methods you can access - it'll save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: Wow. I applaud your response. I was going to try to top that, but as a scrolled through, I really enjoy how this is written. Thanks for the addition to SO.